# IBAction error in subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two class:

1. MeuPrimeiroViewController.h/.m
2. MeuSegundoViewController.h/.m

I have this code:

MeuPrimeiroViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)botao:(id)sender;
```

MeuPrimeiroViewController.m

```
#import "MeuPrimeiroViewController.h"
#import "MeuSegundoViewController.h"
    - (IBAction)botao:(id)sender{
        MeuSegundoViewController *segundo = [[MeuSegundoViewController alloc] init];
        UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
        UIView *view = segundo.view;
        [window addSubview:view]; 
    }
```

This command works great, but in the 'SegundoViewController' I have this code:

MeuSegundoViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)botaoback:(id)sender;
```

MeuSegundoViewController.m

```
 - (IBAction)botaoback:(id)sender{
        NSLog(@"Back messange");
    }
```

But the console log don't return any messanges, and the simulator returns me to the main.m file, why?

Comment: When you say it returns you to `main.m`, it sounds like the application is crashing. Can you post the crash log it produces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
[window addSubview:view];
```

The view belonging to `MeuSegundoViewController` is retained by its new superview (the window), but the view controller instance `segundo` isn't - and it gets destroyed. So, when you press the button you get an exception because the `segundo` instance can't be called.

I doubt you really want to be adding the view as a subview of the window. It would be much better to be adding it as a subview of the `MeuPrimeiroViewController` view, or to have a navigation controller and push both of the view controllers into it. If you use the navigation controller then it will retain the view controllers (and prevent the crash). If you use `MeuPrimeiroViewController` then call:

```
[self addChildViewController:segundo];
```

if you continue to use the window then you need something to retain the view controller (and there is no good obvious choice).

Comment: No problem and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a second to up-vote answers that helped you and tick answers that solved your problem :-)